# Restarting Lag based on Change in Name in Different Column

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to insert lags of a variable into a separate column in my data frame on R. However, I want the lags to 'restart' every time the name in a different column changes.

An example of data is below:

```
        Player  Crosses
   Robbie Brady       11
   Robbie Brady        9
   Robbie Brady       13
   Robbie Brady       15
   Robbie Brady       20
Robert Snodgrass       5
```

I would like the lag of 'Crosses', and I am using:

```
lag(data$Crosses, 1)
```

to help do this. But when the player name changes I would like the lag to restart, otherwise the lags carry over into observations that are not relevant to them. So just doing

```
data$lag1 <- lag(data$Crosses, 1)
```

is no good

I have tried using:

```
tapply(data$Crosses, data$Player, lag, 1)
```

But that generates an array that I can't then enter as a new column in my data frame.

Does anyone know a solution whereby I can enter the lags into my dataframe, whilst also restarting the lag when a value in another column changes?

Comment: Hi, this seems to be a R programming question, not a statistics question, and thus is off-topic here.

Comment: Oh ok, is there a way I can migrate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ave`

```
data$lag1 <- ave(data$Crosses, data$Player, FUN=function(x) lag(x, 1))
```

Comment: I tried to use a different function instead of lag and I got an error message:  "Error in ZLEMA(x, n = 6) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 4)" Is it not possible to use functions from a different package within ave()?

Comment: @WillT-E: You can use any function with ave, as long as the function takes a vector as an argument. The error is likely because one of your groups does not have at least 6 observations (e.g. `ZLEMA(1:5, 6)`).

Comment: - sorry to keep bugging you with questions, is there a way to tell it to ignore the instances where a group is less than 6? The lag function seems to just put NA but I can't figure out how to do that with ZLEMA ().

Comment: @WillT-E: Just check in a wrapper function: `function(x) { if(length(x) < 6) rep(NA, length(x) else ZLEMA(x, 6) }`

Answer (score 1):

We can group by 'Player' and then do the `lag` on Crosses.  This can be done with `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Player', we create a new column ('lag1') as the lag of Crosses.  In the devel version of `data.table`, the `shift` by default gives the `lag`

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 setDT(df1)[, lag1:=shift(Crosses) , by = Player]
```

Or using `dplyr`, we group by 'Player' and create a new column using `mutate`

```
 library(df1)
 df1 %>%
     group_by(Player) %>%
     mutate(lag1 = lag(Crosses))
```